# How to enable ElasticSearchIO parallel reads in Apache Beam?

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I have a simple pipeline working in both Google Dataflow and the DirectRunner that is able to communicate with my ElasticSearch cluster and process some data. The basic process is this:

Read document from ElasticSearch using the ElasticIO connector.

Serialize it into our internal Protobuf

Perform a transform with no external calls or references on the document that outputs a different Protobuf.

Write the resulting Protobuf to another ElasticSearch index.

This works fine for my test cases, but when scaling up to run on hundreds of millions of documents I don't see any increase in parallelism. I've left jobs running for 5+ hours in Google Dataflow and seen rates of 50 documents a second, which is just far too slow to be useful. Our current internally developed system can handle 10k - 20k / sec on a single instance. We have other applications that read very quickly from ElasticSearch, and I have no reason to believe that the ElasticSearch cluster is the limiting factor, yet.

What should I be looking at to make sure that the ElasticSearch read scales up to process in parallel?

I've tried:

Increasing numWorkers. This temporarily increased the number of workers, but it scales down because the ElasticSearch read was not producing enough data to keep the workers busy.

Changed the batch size in the ElasticSearch read. Had no impact.

Edit:
Pipeline setup code:

```java
PCollection<String> dataCollection = pipeline.apply("Reading From ElasticSearch", ElasticsearchIO.read()
        .withConnectionConfiguration(esReadConnection)
        .withBatchSize(options.getBatchSize())
        .withScrollKeepalive(scrollTime)
        .withQuery(options.getQuery())//query needs to be stringified json including with the "query" element
        .withMetadata()
    );
dataCollection.apply("Serialize", ParDo.of(new JsonToProto<>(searchHitTag, failTag, SearchHit::newBuilder));
```

Edit 2:
After reading the split code link provided by @robertwb I think I have identified a problem.
The index name I am configuring in my config is an alias (and in other uses a datastream).  I have a feeling that this section of the `getEstimatedSizeBytes` [code](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/c7f2cab6ea30a63e04847dc45047a8193abc9552/sdks/java/io/elasticsearch/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/elasticsearch/ElasticsearchIO.java#L871) is not properly accounting for a large number of cases:

```java
JsonNode indexStats =
          statsJson.path("indices").path(connectionConfiguration.getIndex()).path("primaries");
long indexSize = indexStats.path("store").path("size_in_bytes").asLong();
```

The stats query on my cluster is going to return a list of indexes under the `indices` key. None of which will have the exact name provided in the configuration.

A cleaner solution may be to use the `_all` object, instead of the individual indicies. The path for the above `indexStats` would be `_all.primaries`.  The `indexSize` path would remain the same.  An alternative would be to iterate through all of the indicies in the `indices` object and total up the `indexSize` for each returned key.

In either case, it is a mistake to use the `connectionConfiguration.getIndex()` on the path to get the index stats, because for a number of reasonable use cases in ElasticSearch, the index name or pattern you use to query the cluster may not be the exact name of the index returned.  This issue would also prevent high performance when working with Datastreams in ElasticSearch, as they will all have a different index name than the datastream name used to query the cluster.

JIRA ticket for the fixes to Apache Beam's ElasticSearchIO connector:
https://github.com/apache/beam/issues/24117

Edit:
I've provided a patch attached to the issue in the Beam JIRA that will resolve this: [link](https://github.com/apache/beam/issues/24117#issuecomment-1315503075)

Comment: Did you try to play with "withBatchSize()" option and increase it? By default, it's only 100 documents.

Comment: Yes. That only changed the batch size for the single, no parallelized read and had no impact on my overall throughput.

Comment: What are you using to read ElasticSearch? I could be that the bottleneck is there if that's not parallelized.

Comment: Sorry it wasn't clear, I'm using the ElasticIO connector from beam.

Comment: Is it splitting correctly. See, e.g. https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/release-2.42.0/sdks/java/io/elasticsearch/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/elasticsearch/ElasticsearchIO.java#L844 .

Comment: @robertwb That is the core of my question. How do I make sure it is splitting appropriately? What do I need to do in the pipeline? I'm editing the question to show my pipeline setup code.

Comment: It looks like there is not much logging there--you could edit ElasticsearchIO.java to add some for better visibility there. (For this part you could run with the direct runner rather than on Dataflow if it's easier.) I suspect the ticket you found, however, is the underlying issue.

Comment: I just started my test pipeline with a modified version of the ElasticsearchIO connector, and I am seeing scaling up to the configured max number of worker nodes. I'm still not thrilled with the overall throughput, but seeing the parallelism in my test set gives me confidence that this was the core issue.

Comment: @Jeff What are these modifications? Are you going to create a PR for this if it solved your issue?

Comment: Hi @Jeff, is your issue resolved?

Comment: I'm going to submit my 2 line PR to the project this week. I have some other tasks I need to address first. Even scaling out the throughput in Beam / Dataflow isn't going to be enough to meet our requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue currently in the ElasticsearchIO connector for Beam that does not handle index patterns or datastreams when getting the index stats needed to complete the `getEstimatedSize` methods. This causes Beam to not parallelize queries against multiple indexes.  Details in the Beam JIRA ticket and I've provided a patch to resolve the issue in the comments on the ticket.

https://github.com/apache/beam/issues/24117

EDIT:
Link to PR addressing this issue:
https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/24186